# How to trigger a route inside a react app in production mode using console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-crawler

I'm developing a web crawler for a website that utilizes ReactJS. This script must navigate through multiple pages. The issue is that their app is heavy, causing each request to take a few seconds to load the content. However, when the link is triggered through their routing system (React Router), the content loads almost instantly.

Is there any way to trigger a page through React Router in production mode? (Using the browser console) Or injecting a component?